# C# create IIS App pool & Website for both IIS-6 & IIS-7

Tags: c#, iis-7, iis-6

How to create IIS App Pool & Website in C# but I am looking for a common code which will work both in IIS-6 & IIS-7. If it is not feasible then let me know how can I know which IIS is running in the target Server machine, so that I can switch my code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] to check IIS version if you use ASP. If you don't, you can use HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse.Server property.

**UPDATED**

```
 System.Net.HttpWebRequest rq = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(yourUrlString);           
 rq.Method = "Get";
 rq.ContentType = "text/xml";
 System.Net.HttpWebResponse rs = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)rq.GetResponse();
 if (rs.Server=="Microsoft-IIS/6.0") 
 {
    //IIS 6 Code
 }
 if (rs.Server=="MMicrosoft-IIS/7.5")
 {
    //IIS 7.5 Code
 }
```

Comment: I am not using ASP.Net rather created a small Console App.

Comment: @skumar Then try to use System.Net.HttpWebRequest, get System.Net.HttpWebResponse and check the Server property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.server.aspx

Comment: Is there any common code which can applicable for both IIS-6 & IIS-7?